# Retrieve BigQuery in JSON format

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm developing JAVA application that uses Google Big Query. I'm using [Google Cloud Java Client for BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery) API.

Can I get query result in JSON format with this API? If can't, how can I get query result in JSON format?

Comment: Currently you would have to use JSON libraries that are specific to Java (someone else may be able to provide a real answer). Based on your question and other similar ones, though, I filed a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35984396) to make it easier to return query results as JSON.

Comment: Does it have to be in Java - what about Python or using the `gcloud` tool?

Comment: @GrahamPolley I'm considering to develop in GO. Can GO do that?